# Simple HTML DOM For Parsing generates Error

Tags: php, curl, html-parsing

I am using Simple HTML DOM Class for web-page scraping. Issue is it generates weird characters against unicode character.

```
à¤¹à¤‚à¤—à¤¾à¤®à¤¾ à¤¹à¥ˆ à¤•à¥à¤¯à¥‚à¤ à¤¬à¤°à¤ªà¤¾ / à¤…à¤•à¤¬à¤° à¤‡à¤²à¤¾à¤¹à¤¾à¤¬à¤¾à¤¦à¥€
```

against hindi unicode character.

```
लेकिन इतना तो हुआ कुछ लोग
```

Its my Hindi text.

When I print screen output it output in same weird characters.

```
function getDomContent($data) {
    $html = new simple_html_dom();
    $html->load($data);

    foreach ($html->find('table[id=content] li') as $element) {
        $content[] = $element->plaintext;
    }

    return $content;
}
```

My Curl function

```
function getContent($url) {
    $timeout = 5;
    $ch = curl_init();
    $user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:8.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0';
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 120);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}

$data = getContent($url);
$content = getDomContent($data);
echo '<pre>Array Content: ' . '<br/>';
print_r($content);
die($query);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding header to my page...

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

It solved all issues.

Answer (score 0):

It seems problem with encodification.
Try use [iconv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) PHP function.

```
$text = iconv("current text codification", "UTF-8", $text)
```

But if you don't know current encoding try set it like global configuration with [iconv_set_encoding](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv-set-encoding.php).

```
iconv_set_encoding("internal_encoding", "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Where to do it exactly ?? before all of my functions or with in function or in curl or somewhere else.

Comment: If you know your current encodification you must use first function after receive text, but if you want use global configuration just use second function before any call of your function **getContent**

Comment: second function done nothing... First function skip my content that is return empty string. if I use it.

Comment: Where you have strange characteres when you get html with curl or when you parse your html with **getDomContent**?

Comment: When I get content `getContent` function.

Comment: Sorry its in next function where I get content in loop. `function getDomContent($data)` because when I die after receiving Curl Content it ends with loading same page on my local.

Comment: Can you execute this function `iconv_get_encoding('all')` before `$html = new simple_html_dom();` and return response. It will give you array.

Comment: Thanks @kitill I solved the issue by adding the html header metatag. `        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`